# LDAPSEARCH command giving exit code 127 java SSH

Tags: java, unix, ldap, jsch

I am trying to run a ldapsearch through JSch by connecting to a remote machine. 
The idea is to check if some remote machines are able to connect to the LDAP servers. 
if i login via telnet to those servers, and run the command-

```
ldapsearch -z 1 -x -LLL -h <LDAPSERVER> -D <USERID> -w <PASSWORD> -b "OU=XXX,DC=XX,DC=xxxxx,DC=xxx" -s sub "(cn=abc.def)" cn
```

The command runs fine. But the same command, when run via a java main class, using JSch gives the following output-

```
ksh: ldapsearch:  not found.

Exit code: 127
```

Please help.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the relevant code from your java program. Also, on the remote system, what directory is ldapsearch located in? How does that directory get into your command PATH?

Comment: Ok, i am not sure of that, but when i use telnet, it works from the any path..

Comment: Also, i checked now, on another server (QA) this command works bit fails on Dev